# Tensor Product of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\Omega$ be a probability space. Suppose $(\epsilon_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables on $\Omega,$ i.e. $(\epsilon_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ are independent and $P(\epsilon_i=1)=P(\epsilon_i=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n.$ Define the r.v. s on $\Omega\times\Omega$ as $\epsilon_i\otimes\epsilon_j(\omega,\omega^\prime)=\epsilon_i(\omega)\epsilon_j(\omega^\prime).$ Can we prove that the sequence $(\epsilon_i\otimes\epsilon_j)_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ is again a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v.s?

Comment: It is true that the $\epsilon_i \otimes \epsilon_j$ will be Bernoulli(1/2). However, I doubt that they will be independent in most cases. There is a heuristic by looking at cardinalities: in order to define $n^2$ i.i.d. Bernoulli's you need a probability space with $2^{n^2}$ points, whereas, $\Omega \times \Omega$ will only contain $2^{2n}$ points, when $\Omega = \{-1,1\}^n$. Though, if you only want pairwise independence, it might be true. Maybe someone can post a real answer.

Comment: @  Shalop. is it not true that among $(\epsilon_i\otimes\epsilon_j)_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ a subcollection would be independent i.i.d. Bernoulli ? E.g. $\{\epsilon_1\otimes\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3\otimes\epsilon_4,\epsilon_5\otimes\epsilon_6.\dots\}$ ?

Comment: The **sub**collection that you just mentioned will be independent, yes.

Comment: @ Shalop. So how large sub-collection can one obtain?

Comment: Well, a lower bound for the largest possible subcollection would be $n$ (because you just gave an example), an upper bound would be $2n$ (again, by cardinalities).